# Cassandra data aggregation and rollup

Tags: cassandra, cql3

which is the best way to aggregate and store back data in a Cassandra cluster? I mean, having a table with hour data, aggregate at day and save in a different table. This can be simply achieved with select and insert for every key/period, but is there a better or different way? What about materialized views?

Comment: Are you in a new enough version to use User Defined Aggregates (UDA/UDFs)? Whats your data model

Comment: A simplified version is CREATE TABLE POINTS (
 id bigint,
 objid bigint,
 ts timestamp,
 avg double,
 last double,
 max double,
 min double,
 PRIMARY KEY ((id), objid, ts)
) 
 WITH compaction = {'compaction_window_size': '7', 
          'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 
          'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy'} and
 gc_grace_seconds=86400;

Answer (score 0):

#### Materialized views

Usage of materialized views in cassandra is quite limited :

- all primary keys from the source table must appear in the view, possibly in a different order.
- aggregate functions like `avg` cannot be used
- `GROUP BY` is not allowed

So I do not think it is suitable for your time-based rollup, nor any other aggregations.

By the way, materialized view has been retroactively classified
as experimental, and not recommended for new production uses.

#### Manual solution

This is great as soon as the data to aggregate is frozen, forever... If not, consistency will be hard to handle.

#### Indexes

A completely different approach to the rollup would be to use [Elassandra](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra) to index the temporal column. An elasticsearch secondary index we'll be created and keep in sync automatically. Then use the embed elasticsearch API to query at different time scales, using [date histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html).

This way the result of aggregations is not stored, but calculated in real-time from a efficient secondary data structure.